# Clear $ionicHistory when particular page is accessed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

[image]

I am having a bit of a problem with clearing [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/).

As seen above when the user clicks on *Ok* on the *Payment* screen, I'd like to clear out the app’s entire view history and redirect the user to the *Nearby* screen.

The view history prior to the *Nearby* screen on which the user reaches from the *Payment* screen needs to be cleared. So the user simply sees a menu icon on the *Nearby* screen, instead of a *Back* icon.

**What actually happens:** The view history prior to the *Payment* screen on which the user clicks *Ok* on is cleared. So when the user lands on the *Nearby* page, and presses *Back* (which they should not be able to do), they end up on the *Payment* screen again, but cannot access anything prior to the *Payment* screen.

**My code so far:**

app.js

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

.state('app.payment', {
  url: '/payment/:business',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/payment.html',
      controller: 'BookCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.service', {
  url: '/services/:service',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/service.html',
      controller: 'ServiceCtrl'
    }
  }
});

// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/services');
});
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('BusinessCtrl', function($scope, $state, ServicesData, $stateParams, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.business = ServicesData.getBusiness($stateParams.business);
  $scope.service = ServicesData.getBusinessServiceCategory($stateParams.business);
  $scope.clearHistory = function() {
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
  }
})

.controller('ServiceCtrl', function($scope, ServicesData, $stateParams) {
  $scope.service = ServicesData.getSelectedService($stateParams.service);
  $scope.businessList = ServicesData.getAllBusinessInServiceCategory($stateParams.service);
})
```

payment.html

```
<ion-footer-bar>
    <div class="button-bar" ng-controller="BusinessCtrl">
        <a class="button button-balanced" style="border-radius:0px" ui-sref="app.services" ng-click="clearHistory()">Ok</a>
        <a class="button button-stable" style="border-radius:0px" href="">View Receipt</a>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: I think `$ionicHistory` works here as it should work. You call it on payment page, and it delete all that is **before** this page but not payment page from history.

Comment: Ah ok. I figured as much. How would I delete everything including the payment page when moving to the nearby page? I think this is what I'm really struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$scope.clearHistory = function() {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
        disableBack: true,
        historyRoot: true
    });
}
```